# PostgreSQL questions

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a function in PostgreSQL and wondering if I can do following:

1. I have an insert statement in every if loop.  Can I pass values like this for formatdate1 and formatdate2?
2. I am also updating a table. Is it how we do it PostgreSQL?

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Check returns void AS $$

   DECLARE
   startDate=date;
   formateDate1=date; formatdate2=date;newDate=date;

   BEGIN
   startDate:= SELECT to_date(lastdate::date, 'MM-DD-YYYY') FROM setup;
   for i in 1..3 LOOP
   IF i = 1 THEN
   formateDate1 := select (startDate - INTERVAL '11 months');
   formatdate2:= to_date(formatdate2::date,'YYYYMM');

   insert into warehouse.memcnts1 (select distinct source,
   formatdate2 
   as yearmo, to_date(formateDate1, 'MM-DD-YYYY') 
    where effdt <= formateDate1 and enddt >= formateDate1);


   ELSIF i = 2 THEN  -- this is todays date
   --insert query here     
   insert into warehouse.memcnts1 (select distinct source,formatdate2 as yearmo, to_date(formateDate1, 'MM-DD-YYYY') where effdt <= formateDate1

   and enddt >= formateDate1);

      ELSIF i = 3 THEN

      formateDate1 := select (startDate + INTERVAL '1 months');
       newDate=formateDate1;



       update dwset SET lastdate := newDate; -- wonder if this is right?

       formatdate2:=startDate;
      END IF;

      END LOOP;

        END
   $$ language 'plpgsql';
   ```

Comment: what happens when you tried it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for question 1.

For question 2, your update statement should look like this:

UPDATE dwset SET lastdate = newDate WHERE foo = bar; -- unless you want to update all rows in dwset

Some other comments:

- What is the point of your loop? It looks to me like sequential code that the loop just makes complicated looking for no apparent reason.
- Where does lastdate come from? Is is supposed to be a parameter to the function?

Comment: @Andrew For Q2, yes it is updating all rows (it has only one record, which indicates the last update on the record). The point of the loop is (actually there are 13 cases(dates)) to insert 13 records for last 13 dates.  the lastdate is a db column. For Q1- I am fairly new to the Postgresql, so I am not familiar to the syntax of it.  Can I pass the values of formatdate1 and formatdate2 after I get them as above.

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr -  Thanks I could.  But I am do not have access to test environment yet.  So I was just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

In general any sort of insert, insert, update loop is going to run into problems if the loop gets large enough.  I assume you want to do something like

```
 FOR 1 .. n
 LOOP
      INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...);
      INSERT INTO foo VALUES (...);
      UPDATE BAR set ....;
  END LOOP;
```

I make that assumption because there is no reason to do a loop and then run different logic for each one.

The problem with the above is that as n gets large (let's say, over a hundred or so) you can start to run into cache management issues which can suddenly start to cause a lot of random disk I/O activity and very long queries.  There is nothing like wondering why a given function call runs through 50 iterations of a loop in, say, 100ms, but runs through 1000 iterations of a loop in 1800000 ms. (been there, done that).

In general you want to try to run your logic avoiding loops and instead perform set operations instead.

I hope this helps.  It is really hard to see what you are asking.